# References versus Entity Reference

Tags: 7, entities

This question has been asked before, but a while ago, looking for a fresh opinion. Many more people seem to be using references (perhaps because it's a port from Drupal 6) but the functionality of entity reference seems pretty good. Opinions? Thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relation vs. References vs. Entity Reference for managing node-reference-type relationships in D7](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13862/relation-vs-references-vs-entity-reference-for-managing-node-reference-type-re)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the only way you will find out is through testing this for yourself. I  speak from experience in using Entity Reference currently in a project with success. It comes down to your needs. For example I needed a way to reference commerce products - which are not node entities - so the references module is useless. Entity reference was perfect for this case and would work with any other entity type.

With the massive change in drupal `7.x` moving from a common mindset of "everything can be a node" `7.x` core has emphasized and shown us the benefits of "everything can be an entity". With the success of entities you can pretty much guarantee that entity reference has a strong future in `d7.x`

I am not sure if there is any advantage in using references since Entity Reference does all that references does, while being much more powerful.

From the project page;

> "Note :
>   - As the past couple months showed, the current maintainers are not up to the task. This module accepts new maintainers.
>   - References will most probably be deprecated in the near future in favor of Entity Reference, which should probably be considered first
>   on fresh `D7` projects."

I think this says it all.

- For the extended future developers should look into [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) which is expected to replace entity reference.

Comment: Thanks, I did read that was a little surprised at the number of people who have opted for the the d7 version of references

Answer (score 2):

As the [Reference module site](http://drupal.org/project/references) says the future for it is not very promising and it will probably be deprecated in favor of entity reference, so there may not be much to discuss :)