# Foreign key for content type

Tags: nodes

I have a content type named 'products' and every product have a unique vendor, so I want to add a field to the content type 'products' that allow me to chose the appropriate vendor from a list.

Is this possible without creating a custom module ?
Can I create another content type 'vendors' and join the two content type ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to reference content types from one another but not with the core field system. There are currently 3 modules that offer this functionality:

1. [References](http://drupal.org/project/references)
2. [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference)
3. [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation)

I'll let you read the module pages yourself to decide which one is best for your use case.

Each of the modules provides a field type that you can attach to one content type to reference another. The fields behave just like any others in the system and so can have a static or unlimited cardinality.

Comment: See also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13862/relation-vs-references-vs-entity-reference-for-managing-node-reference-type-re

Answer (score 0):

may be you could go to structure-> content type->product
then edit product and click manage fields, you could add fields here.
as already said above you should installed fileds, eninty modules first.