# Which module for relationships in my particular case?

Tags: views, theming, entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Relation vs. References vs. Entity Reference for managing node-reference-type relationships in D7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13862/relation-vs-references-vs-entity-reference-for-managing-node-reference-type-re)

I want to figure out which module (and, probably, strategy) will fit my needs best in such a situation.

I've built a site, there are a lot of `piece`'s; each `piece` is either written or arranged by some `person` (or has both relations, composer and arranger); each `piece` can be a part of a `collection` (think of CD for performed `piece`'s or book for scores in PDF).

Here `piece`, `person`, `collection` are types (post types, or node types in Drupal I believe); `score`, `audio`, `video`, `text` etc are taxonomies (in `media` tree). And each `piece` can have any or all media taxonomies assigned. Also there are `genre` taxonomies.

A `person` can be a `conductor` (if `piece` presents some performance by `choir`), `soloist` etc.

So, `piece` can be connected with `person` by a named "role".

Below are some links to demonstrate what I actually want to have (or something like that); the site made with WordPress (using [posts-to-posts plugin](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts)).

However, I don't like what I have: that was the first my attempt to make a site, I am nor a programmer neither designer... I don't know what I am. Anyway, I don't like that site in terms of code maintainability (I guess that's my fault, not WP's), so I'd like to rewrite it; and I'd like to design new theme and have better ("overall php+mysql") performance.

So, now **the question is**: which module should I try for this --- [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) or [Relations](http://drupal.org/project/relation)? Or any other? Can I hope I can get better performance (php+mysql)?

Please, take a look (everything in Ukraine, but there are buttons to google-translate, SORRY):

- here is [Mykola Gobdych's page](http://www.parafia.org.ua/person/hobdych-mykola/) (conductor of Chamber Choir "Kyiv") --- below the photo there are links to other "views" (listen to pieces conducted by this `person`, listen to pieces performed by him, listen to his pieces --- either composed or arranged by --- etc)
- some [`collection`](http://www.parafia.org.ua/collection/rizdvyani-vechory/) of `piece`'s
- a [`piece`](http://www.parafia.org.ua/piece/ne-otverzhy-mene-vo-vremya-starosty/) --- please, note, here are two performances... actually these are two `piece`'s connected with "the same piece" relationship
- [listen to choir](http://www.parafia.org.ua/choir/natsionalna-akademichna-kapela-ukrajiny-dumka/listen/) view

I really would like to try to do something like this with Drupal; however, I am very new to drupal. And I am not a programmer .)

So, please help; I will appreciate any helpful information or suggestion.

Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickKenny Thanks, I saw that topic. However, I can decide by myself whether I have complex relationships or not. That's why I'm asking you, experts. Moreover, I would like to hear something about performance. I understand that not too much people here tried WP, but... anyway. I am really not a programmer and very new to drupal. Thanks again.

Comment: It could be that the language in the answers is to technical, and needs to be explained better. But as far as I can tell, the linked to Question contains all the necessary information to made an educated choice. @Brownian, please comment on the Q that Patrick linked to if something is unclear. For what it's worth, Patricks answer is the best one, not the accepted answer.

Comment: @Letharion well... after reading Елин's answer and some comments I guessed that those relations which I plan to use "are not too complex" (from drupal masters point of view), and Entity Reference will fit. You suggest that I would better ask in other question's comments "whether my relations are too complex or not"? I said that I know nothing about drupal -- I asked not for comparison of two, but which would be better for my particular picture. Ok, nothing about performance, my fault -- I should not ask whether can I get better performance at all. Sorry.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Sorry, I wanted to write "I can NOT decide by myself whether I have complex relationships or not."

Answer (score 2):

Both [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) and [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) modules would do the work, but in your case I would suggest to go with [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module, since you don't have very complex relationships.

Comment: Could be nice to include a direct link to the two modules.

Comment: Just updated, thank you for notice. @KristerAndersson

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. As I need both `piece` to refer to `person` and `person` to refer to `piece` (direct- and back-referencing) -- shouldn't I use Relation module?..

Comment: @brownian No, you don't need to. You should be capable of doing this with Entity Reference module, as well.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. Sorry, I have to try everything. THANK you for your answer ANYWAY. This topic caused my misunderstanding: http://drupal.org/node/1293792