# How do i create a field for a content type from a content type? Like a list for add multiples values from a content type, inside another

Tags: entities

It is simply as a **1 to many** relationship between content and I need to manage multiple content within another.

I do not know if there is any plugin or library or method that allows me to. Please I need help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you elaborate ? From what I understand you want to use a field B (which is in content-type B) in content-type A.

Comment: Have you checked https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference (entity reference module) ? it's a way of building the one to many relationship you need. for more check similar question 
[https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13862/relation-vs-references-vs-entity-reference-for-managing-node-reference-type-re]

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as use the module [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).
You'll have a new field type to reference a node (or multiple) into an other node.